# What is preventing Windows from obtaining new IP from DHCP?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, dhcp

I have Windows XP box, which is getting IP address from TFTPD32 application. So in `tftpd32.ini` I have specified static record:

```
08:00:27:CE:9B:AD=10.10.1.3
```

Now I would like to change that record so Windows PC receives new IP. I modified the record to:

```
08:00:27:CE:9B:AD=10.10.1.15
```

I expected Windows XP PC to get new IP address, but it still defaults to old `10.10.1.3`. TFTPD32 receives the following 3 requests

[image]

After digging into Windows XP registry I found the following:

[image]

I can only guess that Windows is asking something from DHCP server, not getting it and defaulting to last DHCP lease. What can I do on Windows XP to request brand new DHCP address?

Comment: Try `ipconfig /release` then `ipconfig /renew` on the XP client.

Comment: perhaps I'm missing somthing, but the host IP address is not set inside a services config file, so the config line you are showing should be service binding config (eg the host listens on the specified IP for connections), not IP config.  In that case, you would have to get a new IP, either through DHCP or a staticly configured address.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: yes, it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD as administrator on your Windows machine and run the following commands one by one:

1. `ipconfig /release` → to de-allocate the current IP address
2. `net stop dhcp`     → to stop the services of dhcp (if it prompts for disabling win*** or any application, enter "Y" and continue to the next command)
3. `net start dhcp`    → restart the dhcp services
4. `ipconfig /renew`   → get a fresh IP address from DHCP

Comment: Steps 2 and 3 might not be necessary.